# NSJSONSerialization unboxes NSNumber?

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm using `NSJSONSerialization` to turn a `JSON` document into the Core Foundation types.

I have a field in my `JSON` which is a "number". It's sometimes and integer, sometimes a float.

Now, the problem is when `NSJSONSerialization` turns my `JSON` into an `NSDictionary` and I try to extract the number using objectForKey, sometimes it's an int, and sometimes it's a double. It seems `NSJSONSerialization` doesn't simply leave it in an `NSNumber` wrapper, but actually unboxes the value, and inserts *that* into the `NSDictionary`.

Very strange. I thought you we're supposed to put primitives into an `NSDictionary`. So the problem I have now is that I don't know what type (int or double) I should be casting to to preserve the actual number value.

Anyone know a way out?

Comment: No, it can't do that as you can only store objects in a `NSDictionary` so it has to keep them boxed.

Comment: Strange, right? But that's exactly what's happening! I am using AFNetwroking (which uses NSJSONSerialization under the hood), if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get primitive type from NSNumber. Just use following code snippet:

```
    const char* type = [theValue objCType];
if (strcmp (type, @encode (NSInteger)) == 0) {
    //It is NSInteger
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (NSUInteger)) == 0) {
    //It is NSInteger
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (int)) == 0) {
    //It is NSUInteger
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (float)) == 0) {
    //It is float
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (double)) == 0) {
    //It is double
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (long)) == 0) {
    //It is long
} else if (strcmp (type, @encode (long long)) == 0) {
    //It is long long
}
```

And etc.

Comment: Since this would have been a solution had my problem been a real problem, I'm going to mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they were NSNumbers all along, and I am just inexperienced at debugging. I was just confused and thought they were int and double values, because that is how the debugger presents them. So it's the debugger that was unboxing, not NSJSONSerialization...