# A double number's type is Int in Swift

Tags: swift

```
// Swift
import UIKit
let arr = [1, "a", 2.88]
let last = arr.last
if last is Int {
    print("The last is Int.")    // The last is Int.
} else {
    print("The last is not Int.")
}
```

I can't understand the result printed.
Why it print "The last is Int".

```
// Swift
import UIKit
let arr = [1, "a", -2]
let last = arr.last
if last is Double {
    print("The last is Double.")    // The last is Double.
} else {
    print("The last is not Double.")
}
```

And this print "The last is Double".Why?
Could somebody can help me?
Than you vary much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Swift arrays can only hold one type.  When you declared:

```
let arr = [1, "a", 2.88]
```

Swift made `arr` of type `[NSObject]`.  You can verify this by <kbd>Option</kbd>-clicking on `arr` to see its type.  This only works because you have *Foundation* imported (your `import UIKit` imports `Foundation` as well).  Try removing `import UIKit`.

Then, the values `1` and `2.88` were converted to `NSNumber` and `"a"` to `NSString` so that they can be stored in that `[NSObject]` array because `Int`s, `String`s, and `Double`s are not `NSObjects`.  `NSNumber` and `NSString` are subclasses of `NSObject`.  Swift picks the most restrictive type for the array.  Had your array been `[1, true, 2.88]`, the array type would have been `[NSNumber]`.

The interesting thing about an `NSNumber` is that it is an object container that wraps many different types.  You can put an `Int` in and take out a `Double`.  So, it is misleading then when you test it with `is`.  It responds "true" meaning, "I can be that if you want".

---

```
import Foundation

let n: NSNumber = 3.14

print(n is Int)       // "true"
print(n is Double)    // "true"
print(n is Bool)      // "true"

print(n as! Int)      // "3"
print(n as! Double)   // "3.14"
print(n as! Bool)     // "true"
```

---

Note:  Had you declared your `arr` to be `[Any]`, then this would have worked as you expected:

```
let arr:[Any] = [1, "a", 2.88]
let last = arr.last
if last is Int {
    print("The last is Int.")
} else {
    print("The last is not Int.")  // "The last is not Int."
}
```

But Swift is not going to create an array of type `Any` for you unless you ask explicitly (because quite frankly it is an abomination in a strongly typed language).  You should probably rethink your design if you find yourself using `[Any]`.

The only reason Swift creates `[NSObject]` when *Foundation* is imported is to make our lives easier when calling *Cocoa* and *Cocoa Touch* APIs.  If such an API requires an `NSArray` to be passed, you can send `[1, "a", 2.88]` instead of `[NSNumber(integer: 1), NSString(string: "a"), NSNumber(double: 2.88)]`.

Comment: > Then, the values get converted to `NSNumber`. But when i check type of `last` variable it is `NSObject?`, not `NSNumber`.

Comment: `last` returns an optional variable of the type held by the array.  The array is `[NSObject]`.  This particular instance holds two `NSNumber`s and an `NSString` which are subclasses of `NSObject`.

Comment: It seems the compiler is never inferring types to be `Any` or `[Any]`, therefore the only possible way to infer the type of this array (if `Foundation` is imported) is using `NSNumber` conversion and then using `[AnyObject]` or `[NSObject]`. Without `Foundation` the compiler would trigger an error. You can still use `[Any]` explicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `arr`, if you declare

```
let arr = [1, "a", 2.88] // arr is [NSObject]
```

so

```
let arr = [1, "a", 2.88]
let last = arr.last // last is a NSObject?
if last is Int { // is Int or is Double will get the same result
    print("The last is Int.") // because the number of NSNumber is larger than the number of NSString
} else {
    print("The last is not Int.")
}
```

if you declare like this:

```
let arr = [1, "a", "b"]
let last = arr.last
if last is Int {
    print("The last is Int.")   
} else {
    print("The last is not Int.") // Will print because the number of NSString is larger than NSNumber.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array with type `[Any]` to get the desired result:

```
let arr: [Any] = [1, "a", 2.88]
arr.last is Int // false
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have imported `Foundation.framework` you inherit a certain magic behaviour with numbers: if you create array literal with numerical literals that can't be represented with an array of that value type, an array is created that wraps the numbers boxed in a `NSNumber`. If you don't import Foundation (i.e. you rely on just the Swift standard library), then you in fact can't declare the array in such cases just with `let arr = [1, "a", 2.88]` (whereas for instance `let arr = [1,2]` would still work – that would produce an `[Int]`) but need to state `let arr:[Any] = [1, "a", 2.88]` – at which case no boxing to NSNumber happens (NSNumber is not even available) and the original type is somehow retained.

NSNumber is a box that can be used to wrap all manners of scalar (numerical) basic types, and you can use the `as` or `is` operator in Swift to successfully treat any NSNumber as any of the numerical types it can wrap. For instance the following holds:

```
var a = NSNumber(bool: true)
print("\(a is Bool)")   // prints "true"
print("\(a is Int)")    // prints "true"
print("\(a is Double)") // prints "true"
print("\(a is Float)")  // prints "true"
```

It is possible to figure out the kind of numerical type you used sometimes, but it's just not exposed for some reason to `NSNumber` but is only available in the corresponding CoreFoundation type `CFNumber`:

```
extension NSNumber {
    var isBoolean:Bool {
        return CFNumberGetType(self as CFNumber) == CFNumberType.CharType
    }

    var isFloatingPoint:Bool {
        return CFNumberIsFloatType(self as CFNumber)
    }

    var isIntegral:Bool {
        return CFNumberGetType(self as CFNumber).isIntegral
    }
}

extension CFNumberType {
    var isIntegral:Bool {
        let raw = self.rawValue
        return (raw >= CFNumberType.SInt8Type.rawValue && raw <= CFNumberType.SInt64Type.rawValue)
                || raw == CFNumberType.NSIntegerType.rawValue
                || raw == CFNumberType.LongType.rawValue
                || raw == CFNumberType.LongLongType.rawValue
    }
}
```

You can read more on this topic [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198040/how-to-determine-the-true-data-type-of-an-nsnumber) – there are some caveats.

Note also that [the reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/) also states the following:

> … number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created
>   with …

.